# How to validate <p:inputText> delayed and based on bean value?

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a `<p:inputText id="address">` that I want a validation message to be displayed for when `<p:inputText id="validField">` or the referencing backing bean value is `false`. The value is given by `codeAddress()` and there is quite a delay in this JS-function.

```
<h:form id="addressForm">
    <p:inputText id="address" onchange="codeAddress()"/>
    <p:message id="addressValidate" for="address" display="text"/>
    <p:commandButton value="submit" />
    <p:inputText id="validField" value="#{addressBean.valid}"/>
</h:form>
```

the js:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var valid = false;
var fullAddress = "none";

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = (document.getElementById('addressForm:address').value + ", Germany");
    geocoder.geocode({'address' : address},function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var country, postal_code, locality, street_number, route;
            for (i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i) {
                var component = results[0].address_components[i];
                if (!locality && component.types.indexOf("locality") > -1)
                    locality = component.long_name;
                else if (!postal_code && component.types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
                    postal_code = component.long_name;
                else if (!country && component.types.indexOf("country") > -1)
                    country = component.long_name;
                else if (!street_number && component.types.indexOf("street_number") > -1)
                    street_number = component.long_name;
                else if (!route && component.types.indexOf("route") > -1)
                    route = component.long_name;
            }
            if (typeof latLong != "undefined"
                && typeof latitude != "undefined"
                && typeof longitude != "undefined"
                && typeof route != "undefined"
                && typeof street_number != "undefined"
                && typeof postal_code != "undefined"
                && typeof locality != "undefined"
                && typeof country != "undefined"){
                valid = true;               
                fullAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
            }
            else{
                valid=false;
                fullAddress="none";
            };
        }
        else{

            valid=false;
            fullAddress="none";
        }


    });
    window.setTimeout(sendAjaxical, 200);
}

function sendAjaxical(){
//  alert(fullAddress + valid);
    document.getElementById('addressForm:fullAddress').value = fullAddress;
    document.getElementById('addressForm:validField').value = valid;
    jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {execute:"@form"});
    if(valid){
        document.location.href='nextPage.xhtml';
    }else{
        showValidation();
    }
};
```

the UPDATED js:

```
var geocoder;
var map;


function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeAddress() {
    var address = (document.getElementById('addressForm:address').value + ", Germany");
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latLong = results[0].geometry.location;
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            var country, postal_code, locality, street_number, route;
            for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; ++i) {
                var component = results[0].address_components[i];
                if (!locality && component.types.indexOf("locality") > -1)
                    locality = component.long_name;
                else if (!postal_code
                        && component.types.indexOf("postal_code") > -1)
                    postal_code = component.long_name;
                else if (!country && component.types.indexOf("country") > -1)
                    country = component.long_name;
                else if (!street_number
                        && component.types.indexOf("street_number") > -1)
                    street_number = component.long_name;
                else if (!route && component.types.indexOf("route") > -1)
                    route = component.long_name;
            }
            if (typeof latLong != "undefined" && typeof latitude != "undefined"
                    && typeof longitude != "undefined"
                    && typeof route != "undefined"
                    && typeof street_number != "undefined"
                    && typeof postal_code != "undefined"
                    && typeof locality != "undefined"
                    && typeof country != "undefined") {
                sendAjaxical(true,results[0].formatted_address);
            } else {
                sendAjaxical(false,"none");
            }
        } else {

            sendAjaxical(false,"none");
        }

    });
}

function sendAjaxical(valid,fullAddress) {
    // alert(fullAddress + valid);
    document.getElementById('addressForm:fullAddress').value = fullAddress;
    document.getElementById('addressForm:validField').value = valid;
    jsf.ajax.request(this, event, {
        execute : "@form"
    });
    if (valid) {
        document.location.href = 'nextPage.xhtml';
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, the code behind `codeAddress()` runs asynchronously instead of synchronously?

Comment: @BalusC Yes, it does! The geocoder response needs some time. I added the js to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invoke the JSF ajax request when the geocoder thing is finished, not after an arbitrary timeout.

Change

```
geocoder.geocode({'address' : address},function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // ...
    }
});

window.setTimeout(sendAjaxical, 200);
```

by

```
geocoder.geocode({'address' : address},function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        // ...

        sendAjaxical();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I was not happy with that timeout, too. But with apporaches like yours it still seems the ajax request is too early for the geocoders response. Most times the setter methods are not even called and in case they are, the values of the previous request are set.

Comment: I added my new JS in which I even eliminated two global variables... but too often it just doesn't work and the values in the beans are behind...

Comment: You're navigating to `nextPage.xhtml` while the ajax request is still busy processing. Wouldn't you rather send it in the `else` block of `if (valid)` ?

Comment: Oh, thank you for that hint. I found a solution now to get rid of the arbitrary timeout.

Comment: As my original question is still unanswered but the code it is based on changed a lot due to your useful hint, I asked a new question: [How can I improve this detour validation that depends on javascript and bean values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898483/how-can-i-improve-this-detour-validation-that-depends-on-javascript-and-bean-val)